# Image Fading in Java

Tags: java, android, methods

I am facing a problem while trying to do a cross fading in Android Studio. First, I have the following code to do a cross fading between two images. The code works fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public void fade(View view) {
            ImageView front = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.front);
            ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
            front.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(1000);
            image1.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1000);
            image1.bringToFront();


        }

        public void fade1(View view) {
            ImageView front = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.front);
            ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
            image1.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
            front.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
            front.bringToFront();

        }
```

But, when I try to do the same fading using three images, the code doesn't work. it doesn't fade images properly. Here is code:

```
public void fade(View view) {
        ImageView front = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.front);
        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
        front.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(1000);
        image1.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1000);
        image1.bringToFront();
    }

    public void fade1(View view) {
        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
        ImageView image2= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
        image1.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(1000);
        image2.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1000);
        image2.bringToFront();

    }

    public void fade2(View view) {
        ImageView front = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
        ImageView image2= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
        image2.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(1000);
        front.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1000);
        front.bringToFront();

    }
```

Not sure what went wrong. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `R.id.image2` does not match `front.animate..` in the last function (they are transposed animations?).

Comment: I wanted to touch the top view so that it can be touched to perform the fading effect. Not sure what you meant. Can you please clarify?